# Canvas being created multiple times inside image onload() event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my script below, I tried to get the uploaded image resized and return the  file size of resized file.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#file_select").change(function(e) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }

        console.log('looping');
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        // canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas')
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);

        // //Line added
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
        // //Line edited
        this.src = canvasData;
        // //Line added
        console.log(canvasData.length * 3 / 4, ' bytes');
        document.body.appendChild(this); //remove this if you don't want to show it

      }
      img.src = e.target.result;

    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<h1 class="logo">Upload Picture</h1>
<div id="upload_form_div">
  <form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" capture="camera" id="file_select" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
  Uploading your picture...
</div>
```

It works just fine, the images resized and return the size of resized file, however the problem I am facing is the `canvas` element keep creating non-stop inside `img.onload = function(){...}`, which it consumed very much cup resources and my operating system went freezing after awhile. If I removed all canvas relating script here it just work fine, but this is not I'm looking for.

What's happened, how can I get out of this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable to keep track of the canvas outside the scope of `onload`.

```js
let canvas;

$(function() {
  $("#file_select").change(function(e) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {

        var MAX_WIDTH = 100;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 100;

        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;

        if (width > height) {
          if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
            height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
            width = MAX_WIDTH;
          }
        } else {
          if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
            width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
          }
        }
        console.log('looping');
        if (canvas) return;
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        // canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas')
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this, 0, 0, width, height);

        // //Line added
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL();
        // //Line edited
        this.src = canvasData;
        // //Line added
        console.log(canvasData.length * 3 / 4, ' bytes');
        document.body.appendChild(this); //remove this if you don't want to show it

      }
      img.src = e.target.result;

    }
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<h1 class="logo">Upload Picture</h1>
<div id="upload_form_div">
  <form id="upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">
    <input type="file" name="file" capture="camera" id="file_select" />
  </form>
</div>

<div id="loading" style="display:none;">
  Uploading your picture...
</div>
```

Comment: I've tested it works, I did not know that, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Good, to clarify, your `img.onload` is called first when you initially set the src, but then, when image loads and you set the new image src with the data url, the `onload` listener is called again, explaining the loop.